# How can I show error message in login form modal?

Tags: ajax, yii2

I am following this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/806/render-form-in-popup-via-ajax-create-and-update-with-ajax-validation-also-load-any-page-via-ajax-yii-2-0-2-3/) to create a login modal. Now my login action is

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }
    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        return $this->goBack();
    }else{
        return $this->renderAjax('login', [
                'model' => $model,
        ]);         
    }
}
```

and in another view `test.php`, I have a button

```
echo Html::button('Create New Company',
                  ['value' => Url::to(['site/login']),
                   'title' => 'Creating New Company', 
                   'class' => 'showModalButton btn btn-success'
                  ]
                );
```

On clicking this button, it is showing the login form as modal and doing client side validation for required attributes. When correct username and password is provided, the user gets successfully logged in too.

My problem is when we pass the wrong credential's for username or password, it is rendering `site/login` in another page which is unstyled and showing error **Incorrect username or password** there. How can I show that error on modal?

Comment: try to put ajax validation 'enableAjaxValidation' => true,

Comment: Are you using the ActiveForm widget to show your login form? This will show errors for your LoginForm model. Without ActiveForm you need to show manually the errors ($model->getErrors())

Comment: @vishva I set 'enableAjaxValidation' => true, now it is not going to the unstyled page but the problem is, it is not showing "incorrect username or password" error on the form. It is showing the error message in cosole, how can i get that message on form

Comment: @davey yes, I am using the default login form provided in advance template

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ajax validation like below

In form

> 'enableAjaxValidation' => true,

In controller action use below code

```
if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load($_POST))
{
  Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
  return \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::validate($model);
}
```