# Form validation in YII 2 Modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2, yii2-basic-app

In my view page I have 2 modals with 2 active form in same model,

I am using yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm; in my view page,

My first modal in view :

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" id="dialog1" style="display:none;" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" >
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

                <h4 class="modal-title">List Box Details</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="height:420px;">
                  <div class="portlet-body form">
                <!-- BEGIN FORM-->
                <?php

  $form = ActiveForm::begin(['enableClientValidation'=>true,         
                         'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
                        ]); ?>

    <div class="form-body">

     <div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 50px;">
                             <?php  echo $form->field($model,'c_id')->hiddenInput(['id'=>'c_id','value'=>$id])->label(false);  ?>
                             <?php echo $form->field($model,'c_component_type')->hiddenInput(['id'=>'c_component_type','value'=>'2'])->label(false); ?>

                            <div class="col-sm-10" align="center">
                                <?php 

                                    $cmps_names = ArrayHelper::map(Group::find()->where(['and','c_status = "1"'])->all(), 'c_group_id', 'c_group_name');

                                          //  $cmps_names = ArrayHelper::map($data, 'c_group_id', 'c_group_name');

                      echo $form->field($model,'c_component_role' ,['template'=>"<div class=\"form-group form-md-line-input\">{input}
                            {beginLabel}\n{labelTitle}\n{endLabel}\n{error}\n{hint}\n <div class=\"form-control-focus\">\n</div>\n</div>"])->dropDownList($cmps_names, ['prompt'=>'Select group ','style' => 'color:black']) ?>

                            </div>
                        </div>   

                           <div style="height:15px;"></div>   


                         <div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 50px;">
                         <div class='row'>

                            <div class="col-sm-10" align="center">
                               <?php 
                                  echo  $form->field($model, 'c_label', ['template'=>"<div class=\"form-group form-md-line-input has-success form-md-floating-label\">\n<div class=\"input-icon right\">\n{input}
                                    {beginLabel}\n{labelTitle}\n{endLabel}\n{hint}\n<i class=\"icon-user\"></i>\n</div>\n</div>\n{error}"],['options'=>['class'=>'form-control form-control-inline labl','data-comp_id'=>'2']])->textInput(['style' => 'color:black']) ?>
                               <span class="label_status" style="color:red;font-style:italic;"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                              <div style="height:15px;"></div>    

                         <div class="row" >
                          <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4" align="left">
                                <?php 

                                 $cmps_names = ArrayHelper::map(Master::find()->where(['and','c_status = "1"'])->all(), 'c_master_id', 'c_master_name');


                                   echo $form->field($model,'c_list_model' ,['template'=>"<div class=\"form-group form-md-line-input\">{input}
                            {beginLabel}\n{labelTitle}\n{endLabel}\n{error}\n{hint}\n <div class=\"form-control-focus\">\n</div>\n</div>"])->dropDownList($cmps_names, ['prompt'=>'Select group ','style' => 'color:black']) ?>

                            </div>
                         <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4" id="list_column" align="left">
                                <?php 


                                if($model->c_list_column == "" && $model->c_list_model == ""){

                                  $list_model="";
                                  $list_column="";

                                     $select[''] = '-- Please Select --';
                                echo $form->field($model,'c_list_column' ,['template'=>"<div class=\"form-group form-md-line-input\">{input}
                            {beginLabel}\n{labelTitle}\n{endLabel}\n{error}\n{hint}\n <div class=\"form-control-focus\">\n</div>\n</div>"])->dropDownList($select, ['prompt'=>'Select group ','style' => 'color:black']) ?>

                               <?php }else { 

                                $list_model = $model->c_list_model;
                                $list_column = $model->c_list_column;

                                     $select[''] = '-- Please Select --';
             echo $form->field($model,'c_list_column' ,['template'=>"<div class=\"form-group form-md-line-input\">{input}
                            {beginLabel}\n{labelTitle}\n{endLabel}\n{error}\n{hint}\n <div class=\"form-control-focus\">\n</div>\n</div>"])->dropDownList($select, ['prompt'=>'Select group ','style' => 'color:black']) ?>
                             <?php    }?>



                            </div>
                            </div>




    </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-9">
                    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => 'btn purple mt-ladda-btn ladda-button btn-circle' ,'id'=>'btnSubmit1']) ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


 <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn red-intense"  data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

My second modal has the same component, but in that Modal Activeform Field the hidden field data values are changed.

I need separate validation for these 2 forms.

Note:

I have single model,
In single create Page,
In create page,

My error:

When I submit a form, it does not show error in modal,
It automatically reloads the page and modal is closed.

My requirement:

I need an error message when I click the modal submit button without page refresh and modal closing function. When there is no error in validation it should load the page and save the data in database.

Comment: See below link for show errors is modal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42408190/how-can-i-show-error-message-in-login-form-modal/42431912#42431912